# Is it possible to force center a div in html no matter what is its class or its inner div classes?

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

I am trying to center a div that has a few inner div with some classes.
For example:

```
<div class="one">
   <div class="two">
      <article class="three">
        ...
      </article>
   </div>
</div>
```

Assume we don't know what classes `one`, `two`, and `three` are. Is it possible to center horizontally `<div class="one">` and everything inside?

I have tried for example `text-align: center;` as style but it didn't work.

UPDATE:

Actually, tacoshy's recommendation worked, but it is not exactly what I want. Please see these drawings:

This is before applying tacoshy's recommendation:

[image]

This is after applying his recommendation:

[image]

And this is what I want:

[image]

Is is possible to make the books closer together at the center?

Comment: `div` and `article` are block-level elements that occupy the entire available width. Then `text-align: center` center's inline elements. To center block level elements you need to use Flexbox, Grid or `margin:auto`

Comment: Thanks so much. Can you show how can I do it for the above example?

Comment: `.one * { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }` would center every element inside it. But this really changes everything and might even elements that should not be affected.

Comment: @tacoshy it worked nicely! The only issue I have is that for example when I have two articles, I want them to be close to each other at the center, but now they are very far from each other but the whole thing is centered.  Can I get the two articles close to each other and centered?

Comment: @TJ1 can you update your code with the new one? Thx.

Comment: @tacoshy, @TJ1, fyi, with Internet Explorer out of the picture, another way of using inline margin (instead of `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto;`) is to use `margin-inline: auto;` [caniuse margin-inline](https://caniuse.com/?search=margin-inline).

Answer (score 0):

To center an element, the best way in my opinion is by using [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). You just got to add those 3 properties to the parent :

- `display: flex`
- `justify-content: center`
- `align-items: center`

So in your exemple, I believe it's the body if you want to center the only div on your page. Otherwise, you need a way, by aiming a div using an ID instead of class, or with `:nth-child(n)`.

`text-align: center` works only for text or other elements with `display: inline`

Comment: Thanks so much. Can you show me how to do it for my example?

Comment: `align-items` is nor needed as it would center vertically (given that the parent elements height are higher then the child elements). The question was only about horizontal center

Comment: Actually, this didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using CSS Grid? (don't if you are using bootstrap with the css grid option)

```css
.one {
            display: grid;
            background-color: white;
            width: 80vw;
            height: 80vh;
            margin: 10vh 10vw;
        }
        .two {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
            grid-template-rows: 1fr;
            grid-column-gap: 10px;
            grid-row-gap: 0;
        }
        .three {
            background-color: yellow;
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 20vw;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .three:first-child {
            justify-self: end;
        }
        .three:last-child {
            justify-self: start;
        }
```

```html
<div class="one">
    <div class="two">
        <article class="three">
            ...
        </article>
        <article class="three">
            ...
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had a similar answer... +1

Comment: classes `one`, `two`, and `three` are predefined by another framework and I cannot change them. I want to put an outer dive to do the centering.